# Why isnt my Background color working in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

The only part of my Combo Box that isn't working is the Background Color. I want the whole thing to be yellow. But the collapsed part is still just gray.

```
<ComboBox Height="25" Width="125" Background="Yellow">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="One"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Two"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Three"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22695145/107625?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegantly override style of ComboBox's ToggleButton in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799974/elegantly-override-style-of-comboboxs-togglebutton-in-wpf) if *collapsed part* is a button. If it's drop-down list, then see @UweKeim comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work as expected while using wpf with windows 7. However if you are running windows 8 or later, the same may not apply.

This https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/ might help you in achieving what you want.

The author has given a very good explanation regarding the same.

Comment: That article describes my problem exactly. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome Jim! Probably we both might have to thank the author of the article for such wonderful explanation ;)

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this can help you :

```
<ComboBox Height="25" Width="125" Background="Yellow"
          Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ComboBoxStyleKey}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="One"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Two"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Three"/>
</ComboBox>
```